# Infinity loop to an async view serve

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am building a project with Node.js Express and MongoDB. In my NoSQL database I have a collection called reviews which has 5 documents inserted. When I load my index page I want to retrieve some documents from reviews collection.

```
require('./database');
const Review = require('./server/models/Review');

// Index view file
app.get('/index', async (req, res) => {
  const limitNumber = 8;
  const reviews = await Review.find({}).limit(limitNumber);
  console.log(reviews) // It retrieves the documents
  res.render('index', {"userData": null}, {reviews});
});
```

When I load `http://localhost:3000/index` page it seems that it is getting caught in a **infinity loop** even though I have set my function and query as async-await (which means that find query never ends?)

***Note:** I am using Mongoose.*

Any thoughts?

Comment: The third argument to [`res.render`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render) cannot be an object like `{reviews}`, it can only be a callback function.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen What an error :( . I was using res.render to so many places in the project and I missed its syntax. Thank you!